# WooCommerce: How to change text on My Account page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

Need help #WooCommerce #wordpress

[image]

Comment: With just a screenshot of the text that you want to change we can't help you. Please provide us with code that you tried. We can't magically know the structure/code of the site with only a screenshot

Comment: I am using here Woodmart theme with Woocommerce!

Comment: This text is based on WOOCOMMERCE

Comment: So can you please share exact location of file / name of that file.

Answer (score 0):

with a demo account i can help you. Or you can find this php file under your theme files. Search it on theme editor in admin dashboard. Probably the file is in "inc" or "templates" folder but it depends change to your theme.

Comment: Can You please share with me exact location I am using Woodmart theme with WooCommerce. Thanks

Comment: you can request your help from : https://themeforest.net/item/woodmart-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/20264492/support

if you buy the theme they will help you..if you dont..please buy the theme and support developers.